# Conditional types inside interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have an Interface with this shape

```
interface MyInterface {
    otherVal1: string;
    otherVal2: string;
    ...;
    container: 'bank' | 'creditCard' | 'investment'
    type: 'option1' | 'option2' | 'option3' ...
}
```

I need to set types for **type** property based on the **container** property.
For example, if the container value is *bank*, then the options for **type** are for example *option1* and *option2*.In case of *creditCard*, the options ara *option3*, *option4* and *option5* and so on.

I can't find any implementation similar to my case both in the docs and on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```typescript
type MyInterface =
    {container: "bank", type: "option1" | "option2"}
    |
    {container: "creditCard", type: "option3" | "option4" | "option5"}
    |
    {container: "investment", type: "option6" | "option7"}
;
```

When using it, you'd use a type guard checking `container` so TypeScript knows the valid types for `type`.